# Insert new line with incrementing number between each line of text in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run a script in Rthat gets a load of text, finds the unique lines, lists them and then inserts a new line between each line and sequentially numbers them as follows:

```
The cat sat on the mat
The cat sat on the mat
The cat sat on the mat
The bat said drat
The bat said drat
The gnat wore a hat

becomes....
 >1
 The cat sat on the mat
 >2
 The bat said drat
 >3
 The gnat wore a hat
```

The script I have so far just gets the unique lines

```
fileConn<-file("/Users/bilbo/Desktop/output.txt")
longlist <- readLines(file.choose())

lvls1 <- unique(longlist)
writeLines(lvls1, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
View(lvls1)
```

Please help.....!

Insert new line with incrementing number between each line of text in R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
#Test data
tc<-textConnection("The cat sat on the mat
The cat sat on the mat
The cat sat on the mat
The bat said drat
The bat said drat
The gnat wore a hat")

longlist <- readLines(tc)
close(tc)

fileConn<-file("/Users/bilbo/Desktop/output.txt")
lvls1 <- unique(longlist)
cat(paste0(">", seq_along(lvls1), "\n", lvls1, collapse="\n"), file=fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

Here I wrote to a different file with a set name.

Comment: OH. No I wantd to read from one file and then write to another file

Comment: But i think thats what I was doing as file.conn creates a new file and file.choose allows me to specify a different file to read from

Comment: @user3632206 you were right. I was getting my connections confused.

Comment: Here `cat` does the writting to a file. No need for `writeLines` (but you could use that instead if you like)

Comment: OK. Great. As a swansong- how do I give the output file the same name as the input file but with something like 'TBB' to show its different (ie so it doesnt overwrite it?

Comment: That is really a separate issue perhaps worthy of its own question. Comments are not the right place to ask different questions. Basically you'll want to capture the name from file.choose() and then do string manipulations on it.

Answer (score 2):

Another similar way:

```
tc <- "The cat sat on the mat
The cat sat on the mat
The cat sat on the mat
The bat said drat
The bat said drat
The gnat wore a hat"

stuff <- unique(scan(text=tc,sep="\n",what="character"))
# for your code:
# stuff <- unique(scan(file="filename.txt",sep="\n",what="character"))
cat(rbind(paste0(">",seq_along(stuff)),stuff),sep="\n")

#>1
#The cat sat on the mat
#>2
#The bat said drat
#>3
#The gnat wore a hat
```